# How to set a Secure and HTTP Flag on a Cookie only when it doesnt have one? ( .htaccess )

Tags: apache, .htaccess, security, cookies, server

I am currently using this htaccess to add a `secure` and `HTTPonly`

```
Header always edit Set-Cookie (.*) "$1; HTTPOnly; Secure"
```

but because one cookie on this Domain already has this flags, how can I only apply it to the ones that doesnt have it? Because I dont have direct access to the Server it needs to be done via a .htaccess

Comment: What apache version do you have?

Comment: @Webdesigner Apache/2.4.10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following approach will check it the browser did send us the HTTPOnly and Secure Cookie. If those are not include you can set it with the Header command as usual.

```
<If "%{HTTP_COOKIE}" !=~ "m#HTTPOnly.*Secure#">
    Header always edit Set-Cookie (.*) "$1; HTTPOnly; Secure"
</If>
```

This is only working with apache 2.4+

Answer (score 1):

The Solution to this Question was this:

```
Header always edit Set-Cookie (.*) "$1; HttpOnly; Secure"
#Strip off double Secure or HttpOnly settings as if App and Apache sets above you can sometimes get both
Header always edit Set-Cookie (?i)^(.*);\s?Secure;?\s?(.*)?;?\s?Secure;?\s?(.*)$ "$1; $2; $3; Secure"
Header always edit Set-Cookie (?i)^(.*);\s?HttpOnly;?\s?(.*)?;?\s?HttpOnly;?\s?(.*)$ "$1; $2; $3; HttpOnly"
#Strip off double ;; settings
Header always edit* Set-Cookie (;\s?){2,} "; "
```

Comment: Source: https://www.tunetheweb.com/security/http-security-headers/secure-cookies/